# waiting time too long on jquery search bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello I have a problem with a search form .

I have a search function in the DOM (this is not an AJAX request).
This function must be executed when the user types in the form (event input).
But this function takes a lot of time to execute so the search bar is blocked during this time and so the user can't type anything for a few seconds.So what I want is to make the search function run but not blocking the search bar. Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?
PS : I can write only in javascript or jquery

my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#search_bar").on("input", function(e) {
    var value = e.currentTarget.value.trim().toLocaleUpperCase();
    do_research(value);
  })

  function do_research(value) {
    $("tr").each(function(index, element) {
      if (index > 0) {
        var first_name = element.cells[1].innerText.trim().toLocaleUpperCase();
        var last_name = element.cells[2].innerText.trim().toLocaleUpperCase();
        if (first_name.indexOf(value) == -1 && last_name.indexOf(value) == -1) {
          $(element).fadeOut(0);
        } else if (!$(element).is(":visible")) {
          $(element).fadeIn(0);
        }
      }
    })
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think it's a JS issue. I guess you have a lot of entries that your browser can't handle `fading` all of them very fast. So that makes it slow also in typing in the input field.

Comment: show an example of the HTML please to get the best answer here

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do similar things a couple times, so I've come up with a 4 things that are helpful; in order of most impact:

1. **Debounce**
2. **Abort early**
3. **Re-use dom elements**
4. **Paginate output**

**Naive**

For baseline comparison, here's a naive approach. Try typing even short words (e.g. 'hello') and notice the UI freezes.

```js
let $ = q => document.querySelector(q);

let slowComputeOutput = inputStr => {
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
    s += Math.sin(Math.sqrt(i) ** Math.atan2(i, i + 1)) % 3;
  s = [...inputStr].reduce((a, b) => a + b.charCodeAt(0), s);
  return inputStr + ' ' + Math.round(s);
};

let updateOutput = () => {
  let line = document.createElement('div');
  line.textContent = slowComputeOutput($('#input').value);
  $('#output').append(line);
};

$('#input').addEventListener('input', updateOutput);
```

```html
<input id="input">
<div id="output"></div>
```

**Debounce**

The goal with debouncing is to skip inputs if they've been overwritten by newer user inputs. E.g., typing 'hello' will compute the output for 'h' and 'hello' only. In contrast without debouncing, the outputs for 'h', 'he', 'hel', 'hell', and 'hello' are all computed.

```js
let $ = q => document.querySelector(q);
let sleep = async ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

let slowComputeOutput = inputStr => {
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
    s += Math.sin(Math.sqrt(i) ** Math.atan2(i, i + 1)) % 3;
  s = [...inputStr].reduce((a, b) => a + b.charCodeAt(0), s);
  return inputStr + ' ' + Math.round(s);
};

let updateOutput = () => {
  let line = document.createElement('div');
  line.textContent = slowComputeOutput($('#input').value);
  $('#output').append(line);
};

let debounceTimeout = sleep(0), debounceId = 0;
let updateDebounced = async () => {
  let id = ++debounceId;
  await debounceTimeout;
  if (id !== debounceId)
    return;
  updateOutput();
  debounceTimeout = sleep(500);
};

$('#input').addEventListener('input', updateDebounced);
```

```html
<input id="input">
<div id="output"></div>
```

**Abort early**

The goal here is that if the input changes, we abort any ongoing computations that are no longer needed. In comparison to only debouncing as above, typing 'hello' will compute the output for 'hello' only, not 'h'.

On first look, this seems to make debouncing no longer necessary, but it's a good idea to have both especially if you're dealing with e.g. rate limits or task initiation costs.

Note the UI is now responsive at all times, regarless of how long a sentece is typee.

```js
let $ = q => document.querySelector(q);
let sleep = async ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

let slowComputeOutput = async (inputStr, abortObj) => {
  let s = 0;
  for (let groupI = 0; groupI < 2000000; groupI += 20000) {
    for (let i = groupI; i < groupI + 20000; i++)
      s += Math.sin(Math.sqrt(i) ** Math.atan2(i, i + 1)) % 3;
    await sleep(0);
    if (abortObj.abort)
      return inputStr + ' aborted';
  }
  s = [...inputStr].reduce((a, b) => a + b.charCodeAt(0), s);
  return inputStr + ' ' + Math.round(s);
};

let debounceTimeout = sleep(0), debounceId = 0, abortObj = {};
let updateDebouncedAndAbortCheck = async () => {
  abortObj.abort = true;
  abortObj = {};
  
  let id = ++debounceId;
  await debounceTimeout;
  if (id !== debounceId)
    return;

  let line = document.createElement('div');
  line.textContent = await slowComputeOutput($('#input').value, abortObj);
  $('#output').append(line);

  debounceTimeout = sleep(500);
};

$('#input').addEventListener('input', updateDebouncedAndAbortCheck);
```

```html
<input id="input">
<div id="output"></div>
```

**Re-use dom elements**

This one's simple, and I don't think it requires an example. If the majority of latency comes from changing the dom, try to update existing dom elements instead of removing the stale elements and creating new elements.

**Paginating output**

If we're dealing with 10,000's of elements, even reusing dom elements may still have noticable latency. In this case, we can truncate the output to e.g. 5000 elements and provide the user with the option to view all output or traverse pages of output.

Answer (score 0):

I have no proof that this is faster against your DOM but it should be.

1. I cache the rows in the table without the first one (no index 0 needed)
   ss (the big thing)
2. Use a table id (makes the setup slightly faster - micro optimization)
3. De-bounce in a simple way - configurable on time `debounceRate: 500`
4. Localize the functionality in a namespace not look in "window" every function call
5. Short cycle a name match when it is blank (hit backspace to clear)
6. `.show() .hide()` as the fastest simplest way (less code runs) since you had `0` duration anyway
7. Show/hide the list after I get it not individually - might be less DOM churn/re-flow

```js
(function(searcher, jQuery, undefined) {
  var searchThings = {
    rows: {},
    searchValue: "",
    debounce: {},
    debounceRate: 500
  };

  var filterOnName = function(index, row) {
    if (searchThings.searchValue === "") return false;
    let notmatchfirst_name = row.cells[1].innerText.trim()
      .toLocaleUpperCase()
      .indexOf(searchThings.searchValue) === -1;
    let notmatchlast_name = row.cells[2].innerText.trim()
      .toLocaleUpperCase()
      .indexOf(searchThings.searchValue) === -1;
    return (notmatchfirst_name && notmatchlast_name);
  }

  var do_search = function(value) {
    let nomatch = searchThings.rows.filter(filterOnName);
    let showme = searchThings.rows.filter(function(index, element) {
      return !filterOnName(index,element);
    });
    nomatch.hide();
    showme.filter(":hidden").show();
  }

  $("#search_bar").on("input", function(e) {
    window.clearTimeout(searchThings.debounce);
    searchThings.debounce = setTimeout(function() {
      searchThings.searchValue = e.target.value.trim().toLocaleUpperCase();
      do_search(searchThings.searchValue);
    }, searchThings.debounceRate);
  });

  searcher.setup = function() {
    // all but first row (no skipping index == 0 required)
    searchThings.rows = $('#searcheMe')
      .find('tbody')
      .find("tr").slice(1);
  }

})(window.searcher = window.searcher || {}, jQuery);

window.searcher.setup();
```

```css
tr {
  border: solid blue 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search_bar" type="text" />
<table id="searcheMe">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Head? 0</td>
      <td>Skip Me</td>
      <td>Also waffles</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Not Skip Me</td>
      <td>Keep Also waffles</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Cheese</td>
      <td>Also beer waffles</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>1A</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Keep wafe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>cheese bits</td>
      <td>large beer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Jim</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```